# Trying to start Ubuntu, but Grub shows up!

Tags: grub2

I've installed Ubuntu using wubi in windows 7.

It was working fine. But now whenever I start Ubuntu, It says

```
Bash line command editing... grub>
```

How to load Ubuntu now?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on your problem? Grub is required for you to choose between Ubuntu or Windows, so you should be entering Grub before entering Ubuntu. Did you install Windows first, and then Ubuntu on top or the other way around?

Comment: @AsgerBjørnJørgensen Some info is in the question. He used Wubi to install Ubuntu 'inside' Windows.

To Xenon: Which version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: I just added the wubi part! any way I'm using 12.04 LTS..

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods (which does not involve command line) is to boot with Rescatux live CD at http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/, which has the option for GRUB rescue.